# QuickBooks Online API v3 - Refund Receipt supported?

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

Does QuickBooks Online v3 API support Refund Receipts documents?

I was expecting that an entity named RefundReceipt (or similar) existed.

However I can't find any way of retrieving or creating Refund Receipts through the API.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This is on the roadmap for a future release, but it is unknown at this time when it will happen.

Answer (score 0):

According to Intuit, it was supposed to be available as of "the end of February (2014)".  It's not in the system yet.  Source: [Refund Receipt on QuickBooks v3 API](https://intuitpartnerplatform.lc.intuit.com/questions/800008-refund-receipt-on-quickbooks-v3-api)